# How to handle a UX issue that cannot currently be fixed (deleting Facebook posts on a 3rd party site)?

Tags: social-media, facebook

I'm building a small app that scans social media for posts that meet a certain criterion and helps the user delete those posts.

Sadly, Facebook does not allow us to directly delete posts using the Facebook API. Therefore, we have to display a link to the post and tell them to delete it manually. (The post is set to open in a new tab.)

There's a message at the top of the page of flagged posts that explains the process. As we've gotten a lot of complaints, is there any way to help reduce the impact of this issue that we can't directly fix?

In addition, would it be helpful to make it clear that it is a **Facebook** issue and not an issue with our software?

Sadly, embedding the Facebook site is also impossible because of Facebook's security restrictions.

---

Here's a quick mockup:

> [image: Mockup]

Comment: Thanks. so there's no other reason to go to facebook but deleting, correct?

Comment: @MikeM not really

Comment: Just my 2 cents - saying "We have not deleted anything yet" gives users an expectation that you will eventually delete something. In this case, that expectation is misleading as you cannot actually delete anything.

Comment: You may move your app to Electron to bypass cross origin limitations and inject a script to automatically delete the post. Not secure and convenient but it's still an option.

Comment: You say "sadly"; I don't think it's sad. I think it's good. Thank you, Facebook.

Comment: You didn't talk about the process after deleting the post. Is it easy to come back to your application? Does your list refresh automatically after a delete? Maybe the user complains about this part of the process.

Comment: Can you add a mockup of the previous screen in the interaction? Maybe there could be a good change there to stop the users expecting your app to delete their posts.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### Be transparent with your users.

I would include a message that communicates two things:

1. The application did its job successfully
2. Facebook imposes this "inconvenient" requirement

Perhaps something along the lines of:

> We successfully found 105 posts that match this criteria.
>
> In order to keep your account safe, Facebook doesn't allow 3rd-party applications to delete your posts. To continue, navigate to the posts using the links provided, and click the "Delete" link below the post.

I'd also change the button text to something that tells the user that this is the next step towards deletion (because most users likely won't read the *beautifully enlightening* text you provide...).

For example:

<kbd>Delete Post on Facebook</kbd>

Comment: User's may not read the entire message and might assume that clicking on "Delete Post on Facebook" will delete the post.

Comment: I would drop the "to keep your account safe" as it's BS on Facebook's part - the real reason they don't allow it is to prevent someone from making a 3rd party client better than the official app and everyone switching to it.

Comment: "_Go to Facebook to delete_" might be better button-text. And "_Facebook does not allow 3rd-party applications to delete posts. To do this, use the buttons to view each post in Facebook and click the "Delete" link_".

Comment: @rohithpr Perhaps, but the first time they go through the process will be enlightening. Do you have a better suggestion? I like TripeHound's suggestion, however, I was thinking it might increase scannability for a user who's just looking for the word "Delete" if it's the first word on the button. Certainly some quick testing would help clear that up.

Comment: @maxathousand Perhaps "_Delete post using Facebook_" or "_Delete post (via Facebook)_" to keep "_Delete_" at the front?

Comment: @TripeHound Nice, I like those options

Comment: Making the link out use an active verb and give a direction for you and an action for the link might be more clear, "Go to Facebook to delete this post" . You are both taking a command from the user to do what they wanted to do and giving the user directions to complete their task.